# Repost : No setter/field for mblogBegginer found on class

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

No setter/field for mblogBegginer found on class class com.mahmoudradwan.e_news.Blog I defined setters in Blog class already But it gives me error Setters and getters generated by android studio
Tried all answers found in the forum
Any one can Help me ?? 
It's My second post because i didn't get any helpful response

My blog object class

```
package com.mahmoudradwan.e_news;

/**
 * Created by Mahmoud Radwan on 16/08/2018.
 */

public class Blog {
    private static String mtitle;
    private static String mblogBegginer;
    private String mblogIntermediate;
    private String mblogAdvanced;
    private static String mImageurl;
    private String mAudioBegginersurl;
    private String mAudioIntermediateurl;
    private String mAudioAdvancedurl;

    public Blog() {
    }

    public static String getMtitle() {
        return mtitle;
    }

    public static void setMtitle(String mtitle) {
        Blog.mtitle = mtitle;
    }

    public static String getMblogBegginer() {
        return mblogBegginer;
    }

    public static void setMblogBegginer(String mblogBegginer) {
        Blog.mblogBegginer = mblogBegginer;
    }

    public String getMblogIntermediate() {
        return mblogIntermediate;
    }

    public void setMblogIntermediate(String mblogIntermediate) {
        this.mblogIntermediate = mblogIntermediate;
    }

    public String getMblogAdvanced() {
        return mblogAdvanced;
    }

    public void setMblogAdvanced(String mblogAdvanced) {
        this.mblogAdvanced = mblogAdvanced;
    }

    public static String getmImageurl() {
        return mImageurl;
    }

    public static void setmImageurl(String mImageurl) {
        Blog.mImageurl = mImageurl;
    }

    public String getmAudioBegginersurl() {
        return mAudioBegginersurl;
    }

    public void setmAudioBegginersurl(String mAudioBegginersurl) {
        this.mAudioBegginersurl = mAudioBegginersurl;
    }

    public String getmAudioIntermediateurl() {
        return mAudioIntermediateurl;
    }

    public void setmAudioIntermediateurl(String mAudioIntermediateurl) {
        this.mAudioIntermediateurl = mAudioIntermediateurl;
    }

    public String getmAudioAdvancedurl() {
        return mAudioAdvancedurl;
    }

    public void setmAudioAdvancedurl(String mAudioAdvancedurl) {
        this.mAudioAdvancedurl = mAudioAdvancedurl;
    }

    Blog(String mtitle, String mblogBegginer, String mblogIntermediate, String mblogAdvanced,
         String mImageurl, String mAudioBegginersurl, String mAudioIntermediateurl, String mAudioAdvancedurl) {
        this.mtitle = mtitle;
        this.mblogBegginer = mblogBegginer;
        this.mblogIntermediate = mblogIntermediate;
        this.mblogAdvanced = mblogAdvanced;
        this.mImageurl = mImageurl;
        this.mAudioBegginersurl = mAudioBegginersurl;
        this.mAudioIntermediateurl = mAudioIntermediateurl;
        this.mAudioAdvancedurl = mAudioAdvancedurl;
    }


}
```

Articles explore class

```
package com.mahmoudradwan.e_news;

import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.ListView;

import com.google.firebase.database.ChildEventListener;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class ArticlesExplore extends AppCompatActivity {
    FirebaseDatabase firebaseDatabase ;
    DatabaseReference blogReference ;
    ValueEventListener valueEventListener ;
    ListView listView ;
    RecyclerViewAdapter adapter ;
    List<Blog> articles = new ArrayList<>();
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_articles_explore);
        adapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(this, R.layout.article_row, articles);
        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        firebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        blogReference = firebaseDatabase.getReference().child("Article");
        blogReference.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {
                    Blog blog = dataSnapshot.getValue(Blog.class);
                    adapter.add(blog);


                }


            @Override
            public void onChildChanged(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildRemoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChildMoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }

        });

    }
}
```

Log

```
08-20 15:08:06.597 5140-5140/? W/zygote: Unexpected CPU variant for X86 using defaults: x86
08-20 15:08:07.483 5140-5140/com.mahmoudradwan.e_news V/FA: Registered activity lifecycle callback
08-20 15:08:07.519 5140-5140/com.mahmoudradwan.e_news D/FirebaseApp: com.google.firebase.crash.FirebaseCrash is not linked. Skipping initialization.
08-20 15:08:07.520 5140-5140/com.mahmoudradwan.e_news I/FirebaseInitProvider: FirebaseApp initialization successful
08-20 15:08:07.521 5140-5140/com.mahmoudradwan.e_news I/InstantRun: starting instant run server: is main process
08-20 15:08:07.598 5140-5162/com.mahmoudradwan.e_news V/FA: Collection enabled
08-20 15:08:07.598 5140-5162/com.mahmoudradwan.e_news V/FA: App package, google app id: com.mahmoudradwan.e_news, 1:765020936650:android:fd8001655cf26b78
08-20 15:08:07.599 5140-5162/com.mahmoudradwan.e_news I/FA: App measurement is starting up, version: 12780
08-20 15:08:07.599 5140-5162/com.mahmoudradwan.e_news I/FA: To enable debug logging run: adb shell setprop log.tag.FA VERBOSE
08-20 15:08:07.600 5140-5162/com.mahmoudradwan.e_news I/FA: To enable faster debug mode event logging run:
                                                              adb shell setprop debug.firebase.analytics.app com.mahmoudradwan.e_news
08-20 15:08:07.600 5140-5162/com.mahmoudradwan.e_news D/FA: Debug-level message logging enabled
08-20 15:08:07.686 5140-5162/com.mahmoudradwan.e_news I/zygote: IncrementDisableThreadFlip blocked for 5.170ms
08-20 15:08:07.701 5140-5140/com.mahmoudradwan.e_news V/FA: onActivityCreated
08-20 15:08:07.766 5140-5162/com.mahmoudradwan.e_news V/FA: Connecting to remote service
08-20 15:08:07.841 5140-5162/com.mahmoudradwan.e_news V/FA: Connection attempt already in progress
08-20 15:08:08.075 5140-5162/com.mahmoudradwan.e_news I/FA: Tag Manager is not found and thus will not be used
08-20 15:08:08.088 5140-5162/com.mahmoudradwan.e_news D/FA: Logging event (FE): screen_view(_vs), Bundle[{firebase_event_origin(_o)=auto, firebase_screen_class(_sc)=MainActivity, firebase_screen_id(_si)=3366437205721944027}]
08-20 15:08:08.095 5140-5167/com.mahmoudradwan.e_news D/OpenGLRenderer: HWUI GL Pipeline
08-20 15:08:08.158 5140-5162/com.mahmoudradwan.e_news V/FA: Connection attempt already in progress
08-20 15:08:08.158 5140-5162/com.mahmoudradwan.e_news V/FA: Connection attempt already in progress
08-20 15:08:08.163 5140-5162/com.mahmoudradwan.e_news V/FA: Activity resumed, time: 5862461
08-20 15:08:08.226 5140-5167/com.mahmoudradwan.e_news I/zygote: android::hardware::configstore::V1_0::ISurfaceFlingerConfigs::hasWideColorDisplay retrieved: 0
08-20 15:08:08.227 5140-5167/com.mahmoudradwan.e_news I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
08-20 15:08:08.227 5140-5167/com.mahmoudradwan.e_news D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 1
08-20 15:08:08.230 5140-5167/com.mahmoudradwan.e_news W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to choose config with EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED, retrying without...
08-20 15:08:08.230 5140-5167/com.mahmoudradwan.e_news D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 0
08-20 15:08:08.250 5140-5167/com.mahmoudradwan.e_news D/EGL_emulation: eglCreateContext: 0xf19aff60: maj 2 min 0 rcv 2
08-20 15:08:08.284 5140-5167/com.mahmoudradwan.e_news D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xf19aff60: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xf199b8a0)
08-20 15:08:08.445 5140-5167/com.mahmoudradwan.e_news D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xf19aff60: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xf199b8a0)
08-20 15:08:08.640 5140-5162/com.mahmoudradwan.e_news D/FA: Connected to remote service
08-20 15:08:08.643 5140-5162/com.mahmoudradwan.e_news V/FA: Processing queued up service tasks: 4
08-20 15:08:14.009 5140-5162/com.mahmoudradwan.e_news V/FA: Inactivity, disconnecting from the service
08-20 15:08:27.008 5140-5162/com.mahmoudradwan.e_news V/FA: Recording user engagement, ms: 18944
08-20 15:08:27.011 5140-5162/com.mahmoudradwan.e_news V/FA: Connecting to remote service
08-20 15:08:27.019 5140-5162/com.mahmoudradwan.e_news V/FA: Activity paused, time: 5881404
08-20 15:08:27.027 5140-5162/com.mahmoudradwan.e_news D/FA: Logging event (FE): user_engagement(_e), Bundle[{firebase_event_origin(_o)=auto, engagement_time_msec(_et)=18944, firebase_screen_class(_sc)=MainActivity, firebase_screen_id(_si)=3366437205721944027}]
08-20 15:08:27.048 5140-5140/com.mahmoudradwan.e_news V/FA: onActivityCreated
08-20 15:08:27.175 5140-5162/com.mahmoudradwan.e_news V/FA: Connection attempt already in progress
08-20 15:08:27.187 5140-5162/com.mahmoudradwan.e_news D/FA: Logging event (FE): screen_view(_vs), Bundle[{firebase_event_origin(_o)=auto, firebase_previous_class(_pc)=MainActivity, firebase_previous_id(_pi)=3366437205721944027, firebase_screen_class(_sc)=ArticlesExplore, firebase_screen_id(_si)=3366437205721944028}]
08-20 15:08:27.201 5140-5176/com.mahmoudradwan.e_news W/zygote: Unsupported class loader
08-20 15:08:27.224 5140-5176/com.mahmoudradwan.e_news W/zygote: Skipping duplicate class check due to unsupported classloader
08-20 15:08:27.236 5140-5176/com.mahmoudradwan.e_news I/DynamiteModule: Considering local module com.google.android.gms.firebase_database:4 and remote module com.google.android.gms.firebase_database:6
08-20 15:08:27.236 5140-5176/com.mahmoudradwan.e_news I/DynamiteModule: Selected remote version of com.google.android.gms.firebase_database, version >= 6
08-20 15:08:27.293 5140-5162/com.mahmoudradwan.e_news V/FA: Connection attempt already in progress
08-20 15:08:27.293 5140-5162/com.mahmoudradwan.e_news V/FA: Connection attempt already in progress
08-20 15:08:27.294 5140-5162/com.mahmoudradwan.e_news V/FA: Activity resumed, time: 5881552
08-20 15:08:27.300 5140-5167/com.mahmoudradwan.e_news D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xf19aff60: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xf199b8a0)
08-20 15:08:27.331 5140-5176/com.mahmoudradwan.e_news W/zygote: Unsupported class loader
08-20 15:08:27.332 5140-5176/com.mahmoudradwan.e_news W/zygote: Skipping duplicate class check due to unsupported classloader
08-20 15:08:27.352 5140-5167/com.mahmoudradwan.e_news D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xf19aff60: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xf199b8a0)
08-20 15:08:27.362 5140-5162/com.mahmoudradwan.e_news D/FA: Connected to remote service
08-20 15:08:27.365 5140-5162/com.mahmoudradwan.e_news V/FA: Processing queued up service tasks: 4
08-20 15:08:27.386 5140-5167/com.mahmoudradwan.e_news D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xf19aff60: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xf199b8a0)
08-20 15:08:27.499 5140-5178/com.mahmoudradwan.e_news D/NetworkSecurityConfig: No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
08-20 15:08:28.848 5140-5145/com.mahmoudradwan.e_news I/zygote: Do partial code cache collection, code=26KB, data=30KB
08-20 15:08:28.849 5140-5145/com.mahmoudradwan.e_news I/zygote: After code cache collection, code=26KB, data=30KB
08-20 15:08:28.849 5140-5145/com.mahmoudradwan.e_news I/zygote: Increasing code cache capacity to 128KB
08-20 15:08:32.509 5140-5162/com.mahmoudradwan.e_news V/FA: Inactivity, disconnecting from the service
08-20 15:08:38.279 5140-5140/com.mahmoudradwan.e_news W/ClassMapper: No setter/field for mImageurl found on class com.mahmoudradwan.e_news.Blog
08-20 15:08:38.280 5140-5140/com.mahmoudradwan.e_news W/ClassMapper: No setter/field for mblogBegginer found on class com.mahmoudradwan.e_news.Blog
08-20 15:08:38.280 5140-5140/com.mahmoudradwan.e_news W/ClassMapper: No setter/field for mtitle found on class com.mahmoudradwan.e_news.Blog
08-20 15:08:38.318 5140-5140/com.mahmoudradwan.e_news W/Glide: Failed to find GeneratedAppGlideModule. You should include an annotationProcessor compile dependency on com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler in your application and a @GlideModule annotated AppGlideModule implementation or LibraryGlideModules will be silently ignored
08-20 15:08:38.402 5140-5140/com.mahmoudradwan.e_news W/Glide: Load failed for null with size [0x0]
                                                               class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Received null model
08-20 15:08:38.420 5140-5140/com.mahmoudradwan.e_news W/Glide: Load failed for null with size [0x0]
                                                               class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Received null model

Firebase dataBase Example

{
  "-LKIJ4U5ymhgXyt7A4C2" : {
    "mAudioAdvancedurl" : "com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzu@9f1c1e4",
    "mAudioBegginersurl" : "com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzu@c28a776",
    "mAudioIntermediateurl" : "com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzu@b997177",
    "mImageurl" : "com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzu@2810a11",
    "mblogAdvanced" : "null now",
    "mblogBegginer" : "Hello we test desc yarb t4t8l rbna ystrha",
    "mblogIntermediate" : "null now",
    "mtitle" : "Hello it's a test version title Hi hi ."
  }
}
```

Comment: remove that `static` keyword from everywhere in `Blog` class, also drop `Blog.` when assigning - it doesn't make sense, they should all be instance variables not class variables surely?

Comment: set the adapter to the listview after you add the blog values in the list(mean at end of events) and delete the static keyword too

Comment: @MarkKeen Tried that  ....... the same result   :(

Comment: @faiiziiawan When i make it not static i get an error in the listView adapter

Comment: you are setting the adapter to the listview before adding values to the adapter.

Comment: "Tried that ....... the same result" - did you remove `static` from EVERYWHERE in `Blog` - don't you find it odd that the problem is with only `static` fields? "When i make it not static i get an error in the listView adapter" - then you need to understand what the `static` keyword is for, and how for  data classes that setters do not make any sense.

Comment: Please edit the question to explain what **exactly** you expect the final result to be after it runs.  Maybe you also have a database structure to show?  It's very likely that your database field names don't match the names of your getter and setter methods.

Comment: @DougStevenson the field names are the same because data is uploaded from the app , after it runs I expect it will get data from firebase and store it in listView

Comment: Look at the data in the database - is it really what you expect?  Those URLs don't looks like URL to me.  Again, please edit the question to show exactly what you expect the result to be.  What exactly should the contents of the object contain, given the contents of the database?

Comment: @DougStevenson so what i need to do ?

Comment: Article


-LKIJ4U5ymhgXyt7A4C2



mAudioAdvancedurl:


mAudioBegginersurl:


mAudioIntermediateurl:


mImageurl:


mblogAdvanced:


mblogBegginer:


mblogIntermediate:


mtitle:
 that's the structureof my Firebase database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Step 1 : Remove all the `static` keyword from Blog class( even before method names remove it). [static info](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/static-keyword-java/)

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     .....
    //listView.setAdapter(adapter); remove this line from here 
     .......
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {
                Blog blog = dataSnapshot.getValue(Blog.class);//also make sure this line is returning a valid result which can be cast to Blog Class
                adapter.add(blog);
                //listView.setAdapter(adapter); or you can call here but not good approach


            }
        .................

    });
 listView.setAdapter(adapter); // call it here

}
}
```